# Проблемы с видимостью классов

Tags: java

В коде ругается на строчку

```
private ArrayList<QuizCard> cardList;
```

пишет следущую ошибку:

> QuizCardBuilder.java:10: cannot find
> symbol   symbol  : class QuizCard
> location: class QuizCardBuilder
>          private ArrayList<quizcard> cardList;

сам код примерно такой:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class ClassTest{  
    private ArrayList<QuizCard> cardList;   
    public static void main(String [] args){  
    ClassTest test = new ClassTest();  
    test.go();
}
public void go(){
....  
cardList = new ArrayList<QuizCard>();

}
  // и так далее.....
}
```

объясните пожалуйста, в чём суть проблемы??

Comment: кстати стоит заметить что обьявлять переменную стоит не  
private ArrayList<...> =  ...
а так:  
private List<...> =  ...

а инициализацию делать так как и вы (суть в том чтоб использовать общий интерфейс List и не привязыватся к конкретной реализации интерфейса)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так ведь в ошибке чётко сказано

> QuizCardBuilder.java:10: **cannot find symbol**
>
> symbol : **class QuizCard**

Стало быть, нет никакого QuizCard. И ни при чём тут ArrayList

Comment: это код из книги, могу конечно его целиком привети в примерр =)

Comment: Так нету класса QuizCard.. он где-то должен быть описан. У вас точно это не сделано. Это потому, что вы бездумно скопировали из книги.

Comment: оооххх =\\ i`am sorry,  точно пропустил эту часть... вечер голова уже не работает.
Спасибо cy6erGn0m!!!

Comment: нужно самому было класс это написать, а я пропустил это...
ну сейчас доделаю!))

Comment: дописал класс, всё заработало!! урраа))))